# Only allow users to create one review per movie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, rails-activerecord

I have my app setup where users can write reviews for a movie. What I'd like to do is limit the user to create only one review per movie. I've managed to accomplish this in my reviews controller as so:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :has_reviewed, only [:new]
  ....
  def has_reviewed?
    if Review.where(user_id: current_user.id, movie_id: @movie.id).any?
      redirect_to movie_reviews_path

      flash[:notice] = "You've already written a review for this movie."
    end
  end
end
```

Where I'm now having trouble is translating this same logic into my index view template with the helper methods of Devise and CanCanCan at my disposal.

```
<% if user_signed_in? && ... %> # current_user has already created a review for this movie
  <%= link_to "Edit Review", edit_movie_review_path(@movie, review) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Write a Review", new_movie_review_path %>
<% end %>
```

**Also:** Is there any way to improve the lookup in my *has_reviewed?* method? I feel like there's a better way to write it but can't determine the most appropriate fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's what I came up with:**

I created an instance method to retrieve a user's movie review using the `find_by` method on the `Review` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  def movie_review(album)
    Review.find_by(user_id: self, album_id: album)
  end
end
```

This method also comes in handy when setting up my callback:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :limit_review, only: [:new, :create]
  ....
  private
    def limit_review
      user_review = current_user.movie_review(@movie)

      if user_review.present?
        redirect_to edit_movie_review_path(@movie, user_review)
      end 
    end
end
```

Created a helper method for showing the appropriate link to *edit* or *create* a review. Big thanks to Austio and his [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798069/3046413):

```
module ReviewsHelper
  def create_or_edit_review_path(movie)
    user_review = current_user.movie_review(movie) if user_signed_in?

    if user_signed_in? && user_review.present?
      link_to "Edit review", edit_movie_review_path(movie, user_review)
    else
      link_to "Write a review", new_movie_review_path
    end
  end
end
```

And at last this is how I call the helper in my view template(s):

```
....
<%= create_or_edit_review_path(@album) %>
```

Comment: Hi, I have a similar example but I am a bit confused. Do you have @album or @movie?

Answer (score 2):

[Why not use a validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness):

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :movie_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, message: "You've reviewed this movie!" }
end
```

This is considering your `review` model `belongs_to :movie`

---

You could also use an ActiveRecord callback:

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :has_review?
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :reviews
   belongs_to :movie

   def has_review?
      return if Review.exists?(user: user, movie_id: movie_id)
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reviews, inverse_of: :user
end
```

---

> Is there any way to improve the lookup in my has_reviewed? method?

```
  def has_reviewed?
      redirect_to album_reviews_path, notice: "You've already written a review for this album." if current_user.reviews.exists?(movie: @movie)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a has_reviewed? method on your User class?

e.g.

```
def has_reviewed?(reviewable)
   # query in here
end
```

Then you should be able use that just fine in your controller and your views.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but the biggest challenge thus far for me how to go about in getting the `current_user` from within the model.

Comment: This is a method on the user class, so you would have the current user if you called it as current_user.has_review?(reviewable)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do this for both new and create.  Otherwise a savvy user would be able to run a post that would get past your new action.

I would put the link_to in either a helper or a presenter object.  It would generally look like this.

```
def create_or_edit_review_path(movie, current_user)
  return '' if current_user.blank?

  if current_user.review.present?
    #Generate review edit link
  else
    #generate new link
  end 
end
```

After that in all of your views it would just be

```
<%= create_or_edit_review_path(@movie, current_user) %>
```

Then in your controller for both new and create you could do either a before action or just redirect on each.

```
before_action :enforce_single_review, only: [:create, :new]

def enforce_single_review
  if current_user.review.present?
    redirect_to review_path(current_user.review)
  end
end
```

Comment: For that helper method, you'd need the word `def` at the beginning, correct?

Comment: I also should've noted that a user `has_many` reviews. So basically for the 3rd line of that helper method I get, `undefined method 'review' for #<User:0x007fd631e209c8>` being that it isn't a `has_one` association.

Comment: So then will have to adjust this a little later.   Same concept though just check if the user has a movie review for the movie passed into helper.