# How to make it so users can only submit one comment for one post in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797921/only-allow-users-to-create-one-review-per-movie) with a similar concept, but I'm getting a pretty big bug that I think is in my comment controller. The top solution on that page works in that users can only submit one comment per one post, but if they try to comment again, it still gets posted, just not under that user_id. Then, if they try to post a third comment, the functionality works (as the user_id is nill for the 2nd comment) and they can't post it. So in all, users can post 2 comments, one properly with their user_id and one improperly with a user_id set as nill. Please help find the problem! edit: oh and when the 2nd comment submits, the error "Your comment could not be saved. Please make sure to submit valid input only!" still comes up. But the comment is still posted

**Comment Controller:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post
    before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update, :comment_owner]
    before_action :comment_owner, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

    def new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:title, :content))
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        if @comment.user_id != nil #Here I tried to check to make sure a post couldn't submit with a nil user_id, it's still submitting
           @comment.save
           redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Your commment could not be saved. Please make sure to submit valid input only!"
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        end
    end

    def show
        @comments = Comment.find(params[:id])   
    end

    def destroy
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end


    def edit
        @comments = Comment.find(params[:id])   

    end

    def update
        if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:title, :content))
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else

            render 'edit'
        end

    end


    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end
    def find_comment
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def comment_owner
        unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id
            flash[:notice] = "Not your comment"
            redirect_to @post
        end
    end

end
```

**And my comment model:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id, message: "You've already made a comment!" }

    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**user model, if it matters:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Comment: I just added the `optional` section after you accepted my answer, check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey your issue comes from this chunk:

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:title, :content))
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.user_id != nil #Here I tried to check to make sure a post couldn't submit with a nil user_id, it's still submitting
     @comment.save
     redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Your commment could not be saved. Please make sure to submit valid input only!"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

- You have filter `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]` so `current_user` in above code is always `not nil`
- `@post.comments.create` will create redundant `comment` before your check
- You assign `@comment.user_id = current_user.id` then check `if @comment.user_id != nil`, this is weird, `@comment.user_id` couldn't be `nil`

So I think the code will be refactored to:

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_create_params)
  unless @comment.save
    # Why don't use
    # flash[:alert] = @comment.errors.full_messages.join('<br>')
    # The error message will be clear
    flash[:notice] = "Your commment could not be saved. Please make sure to submit valid input only!"
  end
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def comment_create_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :content).merge({
    user_id: current_user.id
  })
end
```

**Optional**

Otherwise, to make sure data consistent, you may modify you model a bit:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # .. your current code
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Moreover, this is maybe not enough, add a DB check level will be perfect.